# Generating both browserify output & System.register() modules from ES6 modules?

Tags: browserify, ecmascript-6, babeljs, traceur, systemjs

I have coded ES6 modules as per [2ality](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)'s final syntax example, without a `.js` suffix.

I have as well organised the modules into a [vendor/project](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) directory hierarchy and module naming scheme as `System.register()` module format effectively places registered modules into the same namespace.

The problem is as follows, if I quote 2ality's example:

```
//------ lib.js ------
export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
export function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}

//------ main.js ------
import { square, diag } from 'lib';
console.log(square(11)); // 121
console.log(diag(4, 3)); // 5
```

The above works fine directly in the browser, e.g., with [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) and [es6-module-loader](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader) (see [`example-es6-modules.html`](https://bitbucket.org/gso/eonjs/src/)).  When the `import` declaration is encountered a `.js` suffix seems to be automatically appended to the filename, and `lib.js` is loaded.  As long as `System.paths` is configured to point to the top of the vendor/project directory then ES6 modules can be executed directly in the browser.

The above also works fine when bundling into a single `System.register()` module format file with [SystemJS builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) (see [`example-system-register.html`](https://bitbucket.org/gso/eonjs/src/)).  As long as `baseURL` is set to the top of the vendor/project hierarchy (see [builder.js](https://bitbucket.org/gso/eonjs/src/)) when generating the modules then modules are named with a vendor/project prefix.

The problem is when I attempt to generate CommonJS modules for input to [browserify](http://browserify.org/), when carrying out the transform both `traceur` and [`es6ify`](https://github.com/thlorenz/es6ify) do not append a `.js` suffix to file names in an `import` declaration, resulting in errors along the following lines:

```
$ cd src/es6
$ traceur --out ./out.js --modules commonjs gso/eonjs/EonJS.js

Error: File not found '/home/ ... /src/es6/gso/eonjs/MomentRecurRule'
```

The above error is because traceur has not added a `.js` suffix to the `'gso/eonjs/MomentRecurRule'` import declaration.  Otherwise the file would be found.

If ES6 modules are transcompiled to individual CommonJS modules browserify reports the equivalent error, cannot find the file to import - browserify does not similarly automatically add a `.js` suffix to the import filename either.

The problem then is, ES6 modules execute in a browser without a problem, load as bundled `System.register()` modules also, but how to transform to a browser executable?

Comment: The same question seems to have been asked here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882004/using-es6-modules-with-traceur-in-single-build-file

Comment: check my solution if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882004/using-es6-modules-with-traceur-in-single-build-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [browserify API](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#brequirefile-opts) aliasing module IDs for relative paths:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');

var b = browserify();
b.add('./index.js');

b.require('./gso/eonjs/EonJS.js',  { expose: 'gso/eonjs/EonJS' });
b.require('./gso/eonjs/AbstractRecurRule.js', { expose: 'gso/eonjs/AbstractRecurRule' });
b.require('./gso/eonjs/MomentRecurRule.js', { expose: 'gso/eonjs/MomentRecurRule' });
b.require('./gso/eonjs/RRuleRecurRule.js', { expose: 'gso/eonjs/RRuleRecurRule' });
b.require('./gso/eonjs/RecurRuleContainer.js',  { expose: 'gso/eonjs/RecurRuleContainer' });
b.require('./gso/eonjs/Occurrence.js',  { expose: 'gso/eonjs/Occurrence' });

b.bundle().pipe(process.stdout);
```

At a quick glance CommonJS resolves module ID strings in a manner similar to `System.import()` (see RrequireJS [Load JavaScript Files](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles)).  However browserify requires this additional aliasing step.

[grunt-browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify#require) task:

```
    browserify: {
        options: {  // https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browserifyfiles--opts
            require: [
                './src/commonjs/build/gso/eonjs/EonJS.js:gso/eonjs/EonJS',
                './src/commonjs/build/gso/eonjs/AbstractRecurRule.js:gso/eonjs/AbstractRecurRule',
                './src/commonjs/build/gso/eonjs/MomentRecurRule.js:gso/eonjs/MomentRecurRule',
                './src/commonjs/build/gso/eonjs/RRuleRecurRule.js:gso/eonjs/RRuleRecurRule',
                './src/commonjs/build/gso/eonjs/RecurRuleContainer.js:gso/eonjs/RecurRuleContainer',
                './src/commonjs/build/gso/eonjs/Occurrence.js:gso/eonjs/Occurrence'
            ]
        },
        debug: {
            debug: true,
            src: './index.js',
            dest: 'src/browserify/eonjs-traceur-debug.js'
        },
    },
```